# C# async await Task.delay in Action

Tags: c#, asynchronous, action, async-await

I'm having some trouble getting a task to asynchronously delay.  I am writing an application that needs to run at a scale of tens/hundreds of thousands of asynchronously executing scripts.  I am doing this using C# Actions and sometimes, during the execution of a particular sequence, in order for the script to execute properly, it needs to wait on an external resource to reach an expected state.  At first I wrote this using Thread.Sleep() but that turned out to be a torpedo in the applications performance, so I'm looking into async/await for async sleep.  But I can't get it to actually wait on the pause!  Can someone explain this?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var sync = new List<Action>();
        var async = new List<Action>();

        var syncStopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        sync.Add(syncStopWatch.Start);
        sync.Add(() => Thread.Sleep(1000));
        sync.Add(syncStopWatch.Stop);
        sync.Add(() => Console.Write("Sync:\t" + syncStopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + "\n"));

        var asyncStopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        sync.Add(asyncStopWatch.Start);
        sync.Add(async () => await Task.Delay(1000));
        sync.Add(asyncStopWatch.Stop);
        sync.Add(() => Console.Write("Async:\t" + asyncStopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + "\n"));

        foreach (Action a in sync)
        {
            a.Invoke();
        }

        foreach (Action a in async)
        {
            a.Invoke();
        }
    }
```

The results of the execution are:

> Sync:   999
>
> Async:  2

How do I get it to wait asynchronously?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're running into a problem with `async void`. When you pass an `async` lambda to an `Action`, the compiler is creating an `async void` method for you.

As a best practice, you should avoid `async void`.

One way to do this is to have your list of actions actually be a `List<Func<Task>>` instead of `List<Action>`. This allows you to queue `async Task` methods instead of `async void` methods.

This means your "execution" code would have to wait for each `Task` as it completes. Also, your synchronous methods would have to return `Task.FromResult(0)` or something like that so they match the `Func<Task>` signature.

If you want a bigger scope solution, I recommend you strongly consider TPL Dataflow instead of creating your own queue.